# resolving circular dependencies / JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency between some JS files and steps to solve.

### Q1: is moving the `require` an OK solution?

One way to get code working is to simply move the `require()` statement inside a function, like:

```
  static getTokens(qo) {
    const FaqModel = require('../FaqModel')
    // do stuff with FaqModel is OK now
```

Does this mean that the require would run on every call of the `getTokens()` method? Seems nasty to me.
Or is this workaround a good enough solution?

### Q2 discovery method

This is not a simple case of A req B and B req A. There is a cycle between multiple files somewhere. Last time I looked the tools to discover the dependency didn't give clear answers, so wondering how best people track this down?

### Q3 refactoring strategy

I am planning to refactor out of `FaqModel` everything needed to a third file and just require that from each case where the circular deps are being caused, eg so the requires only go in one direction. If possible to have a hierarchy of files, so you only ever require *down* and not **up**. But this seems rather simplistic. 
At a high level, what other approaches are there to avoiding circular deps in your design?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Also, tell us what the environment is. (Node.js? Or a CommonJS implementation of some kind?) Node.js, for instance, handles circular dependencies.

Comment: There are multiple source code files involved, so I'm not going to post a full implementation. In any case the question is not to solve a single isolated case, but general strategies how to approach this. nodeJS FYI does NOT handle circular deps very well, it just creates an empty object so the parser doesn't get locked in a loop.

Comment: No one asked you to post a full implementation; please read the linked help page. And again: Please specify the environment. If it's Node.js, please say so (adding the tag would be sufficient).

Comment: "*Does this mean that the require would run on every call of the getTokens() method?*" - yes. But `require` caches the module object and just returns it again, it doesn't load and evaluate your module code again.

Comment: "*nodeJS does NOT handle circular deps very well, it just creates an empty object*" - that's exactly the solution. Do *populate* that `exports` object by creating properties on it, do not overwrite `module.exports`.

Comment: @Bergi so you mean rather than just `module.exports = Namespace` create an exportable object that already has properties, that are the same name as the functions in the original namespace? If you can make an answer maybe I can see what you mean more clearly.

Comment: @dcsan I mean not creating your own object but instead modifying the already existing `module.exports` object. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Answer (score 0):

More details would be needed to give you an answer on how to solve your particular dependency issues. However, this is a good strategy to help identify the problem:

Comment out everything and slowly add features back in. Start with the features that require the least # of dependencies and work your way towards the ones with more dependencies. Eventually things will break. If you did this incrementally, this should help you to find one or more dependencies involved in this problem.

Comment: yeah i did this, but it's a pretty blunt instrument method.